# How to increment build number for xcode project with Azure DevOps

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have an iOS project, for CI/CD was selected Azure DevOps, I created pipeline and configured it according to documentation. It creates builds and upload to Apple Center, the only one thing I cant find out how to manage is how to increment build number, now I am doing it manually in xcode before generating a build.

Before we used fastlane, and it has such a possibility. So the question is how to increment build number with Azure pipeline, or at least force it to run fastlane file, to do it before the build is created?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Update:

Its after creation of test project and installing extension Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android, I cant add it to the list of tasks  in the pipeline:
[image]
How to include it?

**Update**:

In case someone struggling as me:
After I wrote into support, so the issue was quit simple:
"And these task points these new available Android tasks and iOS tasks, we can view them from the Utility tasks when selecting tasks in pipelines, as below."
[image]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Hugh Lin - MSFT I am trying to test proposed extension, but unfortunately I dont have rights to add it to Appcenter (cause of holidays no one will add it), so currently I try to create my free project and test it, after it I will update the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the [Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks) extension that gives you the ability to "bump version":

> Change app's version name and code at build time.
>
> **Inputs:**
>
> sourcePath: Path to info.plist
>
> versionCode: code number that must be an integer
>
> versionCodeOffset: a specific number to increment the version code
>
> versionName: user visible name (short code)
>
> printFile: output the file before and after changing variables

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice, could you ones more help, maybe its a stupid question, but I am not able to add this extension to pipeline, I have update the question. Thanks in advance